# Web.py authoring efficiency

Tags: python, web.py

I am new to python web frameworks. I am using web.py because I like how raw it is. I am wondering though, how one can produce pages and scripts efficiently when being restricted to sending output through the `return` keyword? It seems like for any python module you can only send one thing to the browser, even if it is a large string. What am I missing about the python way of server-side scripting? If it helps, I am coming from a PHP perspective. I am used to being able to say print "foo" and foo will appear. Now I am only allowed to print once per module. If you could point me in the direciton of a python approach to scripting vs the php approach I'd much appreciate it! I'm awful confused at this point how python can be so efficient while being so limited.

For example, here is a basic program I wrote:

```
 import web
 urls = ('/','index')
 class index:
     def GET(self):
         return "foo" ///Where this is the only place on the file I can output anything
 (and the rest of the file you should be familiar with)
```

The point is that it appears to me that the only place you could output anything is in the one return line? Now I understand that if the URI arguments change, you can map to a different class and thus output something differently, but even then this seems limited?

Or ultimately, is the point of the web framework to use 'templates' as they are called in web.py?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is what templates are for: to efficiently separate logic from presentation.

You have to query all data in your controller class and then pass it to template that will output html.

This might seem different from common php practices, but I'm sure even php developers are choosing this approach.

Regarding web.py, another option to stream content output is by using `yield`, see http://webpy.org/cookbook/streaming_large_files

Answer (score 1):

Andrey Kuzmin's answer is correct, and templates are the correct way to work.

However, if you do want to generate the text that you return in a php 'print ("blah");' sort of manner, you can work like this:

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        output = []
        # do stuff...
        output.append('Some text.')
        # do more stuff...
        output.append('And more text...')
        # ok, now we're at the end:
        return '<br/>'.join(output)
```

This will return to the browser/client all of the text you've appended into the 'output' list, joined together with HTML line breaks.

Again though, templates are almost always a better way to work.

**Why are templates and a single 'return' better?**

In PHP it's very easy to 'print' stuff to the output, and it can be convenient.  However, imagine the following:

```
<?php
    include('foobar.php');
    header('Content-Type: Application/JSON');
    print ('{"message": "Hello World!"}');
?>
```

Great, right?
The trouble is that say you have an error in the file you're trying to include (foobar).  Now the PHP error message will be returned to the client *before* the HTTP header, which will cause another PHP error, and a messed up page.

OR,

The foobar.php file has some print statements in it.  Again, you now have errors printed before the header, or even if you're not doing custom headers, you still end up with invalid documents.  So in PHP, the solution is something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    ob_start(); // start caching all output, so it doesn't interfere.
    include('foobar.php');
    do_other_stuff();
    ob_end_flush(); // print the cached output.
?>
```

Which, although somewhat bulky, stops that problem.
Now you have the situation - what if one of your include files *also* is using ob_start() or other output caching?  As long as there are no errors in their code, you should be alright.  But if there are errors, and php crashes before getting to your flush, you will lose that information.

Working with a single end point, as in Python, means that you have a lot more control over what is returned.  In some old legacy PHP code I had to maintain sometimes something (possibly an error message) would be printed, and I'd have to search through the whole code base to try and find where it was being printed.

**How do I print debug messages then?**

In Python, there is the very helpful 'logging' module (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html, or google for more tutorials) which allows you to log all error messages to a file, or multiple files.  You can then 'tail -f' that file, while testing, and observe all the errors or debugging information as it happens, rather than waiting for it in the browser, where it can get messed up or confused by the CSS or HTML formatting.

This also means there is much less chance of you accidentally sending debugging messages (possibly with sensitive information) to the browser, and you can switch between logging levels (loads of debugging info, errors only, etc) while the site still keeps the final production appearance.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='my_application.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# do stuff....
log.debug('This is a debug message')
# do more stuff
log.error('Oh no! This should not happen!')
# ...
```

You will now get a file called my_application.log which has all the error & debugging messages, something like:

```
appname:DEBUG:This is a debug message
appname:ERROR:Oh no! This should not happen!
```

To stop displaying the debugging messages, you simply change the level from logging.DEBUG to logging.ERROR, or whichever other level you want, and you'll only get the ERRORs.  The linked tutorial has much more information.

I hope you find this helpful!